# Chromium Ignoring z-Index

Tags: html, css, html5-video, z-index, chromium

I'm unable to get Chromium to allow me to overlay text or images over an inline video. I've tried setting the z-index (both in CSS and JS); I've tried adjusting the z-index after the video has already started playing, but no luck.

HTML:

```
    <span id="text">test</span>
    <video playsinline autoplay muted loop>
        <source src="https://rawgit.com/bower-media-samples/big-buck-bunny-480p-30s/master/video.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    </video>
```

CSS:

```
    video {
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        object-fit: cover;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
        top: 50px;
        left: 0;
    }

    #text {
        color: red;
        font-size: 100px;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 9999;
    }
```

I have a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lorkel/o1g17817/) that works correctly in FF/Chrome/Safari; it's just not working on Chromium... the text stays behind the video.

Is there any way I can overlay over this inline video?

Comment: Works fine here with Chromium v57.0.2987.98 64 bit under KDE. The video is larger than in SeaMonkey though (420x300, it's 300x300 in SeaMonkey, cut off to the right).

Comment: This might be an older version of Chromium, possibly 37. I have no control over updating it, so I wonder if this older version just won't support inline videos.